# ¿Donde esta este menú en Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Intento que una aplicación creada con Visual Studio sea compatible con Windows XP y necesito encontrar esta opción para poder llevar esta acción como me habían mencionado pero nose como llegar a ese Menu no se si exista o no. Es la opcion:

> "Platform Toolset"  - Visual Studio 2015- Windows XP(v140_xp)"

Nota: Yo tengo Visual Studio en español

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La imagen muestra la ventana de propiedades de un proyecto de C/C++ a la cuál puedes acceder desde el explorador de solución haciendo clic con el botón derecho sobre el proyecto en cuestión y seleccionando Propiedades del menú de contexto.

Hasta donde sé, la opción "Platform Toolset" aplica unicamente para proyectos C/C++ y no para proyectos de otros lenguajes como C# o VB.NET.

Comment: Todavía no logro encontrar ese menu ...

Answer (score 0):

> Para acceder a las páginas de propiedades, elija Proyecto > Nombre del proyecto Propiedades en el menú principal, o haga clic con el botón derecho en el nodo del proyecto en el Explorador de soluciones y elija Propiedades.

Eso pone en este link de la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-160)

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.